# Java Library for Activities/Chain-of-Responsibility with Transaction Support

Tags: java

I have to implement a number of activities (for example, update a user's profile, transfer points from one user to another, etc...), each of which can be composed by one or more logical steps (check if user has enough points, subtract points from the first user, check if the other user can receive then, credit these points to the second user) in a given order. I also need to implement some kind of "rollback" mechanism so that I can undo any previous steps if something goes wrong with step N (kind of what one usually foods in database transactions, except for the fact that a database may or may not be involved).

Are there any Java libraries which can help me with this? I've had a look at Drools but it seems overly complex. Also, I'm not sure it supports this kind of rollback mechanism. Any ideas?

Comment: You can use an in-memory database with transaction support even if this is not an external requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [JTA specifications](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/jta/index.html) is a framework defining a standard behavior for *java transactions*.

A typical and well known use case is the simple database transaction, but JTA is far more generic. It's a framework to manage transaction over one or more transactional resource. A transactional resource can be a database of course, but it can also be a file, a messaging service, ...

If you have multiple transactionnal resources implied in one transaction, you must search for a JTA implementation supporting [XA-Transactions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19509-01/820-5892/ref_xatrans/index.html).(and here is [another interesting link about XA](http://java.dzone.com/articles/xa-transactions-2-phase-commit))

I don't say that this is a simple framework... but the problem you are facing is not simple at all.

Answer (score 0):

If you've got to integrate with other services/providers through REST/SOAP/EJBs/etc. then I recommend looking at [Apache Camel](http://camel.apache.org).  Camel is an integration service that can integrate with pretty much every service or protocol out there.  And, I believe, it supports rudimentary transactions.  You can make a single service call and Camel will handle the routing and integration with whatever backend services you define.  And, you can chain them.  So, your flow would look like this:

Client makes call to service 'FOO'...
'FOO' is defined as a route that makes a REST call to '/bar', followed by an EJB call to 'MyService', followed by persisting the results to a SQL database, and then lastly calling a SOAP web service.  The client then gets back the return value from this call, which can be whatever transformation or permutation of these calls you want.  It's completely transparent to the client where the result came from.